# Is it safe to install MS17-010 unpatched OS as guest on patched host?

Tags: windows, cve, windows-server, wannacry, smb

For example, these are unpatched old OS.

- Windows 98
- Windows 98 SE
- Windows ME
- Windows NT 4.0
- Windows 2000

Given that SMBv1 is not disabled on host but already patched.

Is the unpatched guest OS itself still vulnerable on already patched host?

---

WannaCry Ransomware: Patch released for Microsoft Windows XP, Server 2003 and 8
https://soggi.org/news/WannaCry-Ransomware-Patch-for-Microsoft-Windows-XP-Server-2003-8.htm

Answer (score 1):

If the guest is unpatched and has the vulnerability present then yes it is vulnerable. If the guest has any of its interfaces NAT’ed or Bridged to an unprotected network then the guest is exploitable via WannaCrypt.